# What is the name of the 3 controls used in each picker dialog class?

Tags: android

I can't find the name of the controls used in these dialogs. I'm talking about the *3 up-down sliding selection controls* used in each picker dialog.

[image]

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: looks to me like they are combination of button and TextView/ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `NumberPicker`. You can see the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker and TimePicker

DatePicker

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

TimePicker

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html